# How to automate testing of Pivotal CRM

Tags: testing, automation, pivotal-crm

Has anyone managed to find an automation framework/tool that can inspect Pivotal CRM? I have looked at numerous frameworks and tools and none are able to hook into the application to provide any useful information. QTP has come the closest with the ability to locate most buttons, but still a lot of items that are displayed are not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see Pivotal CRM is .NET application. So you may use [Coded UI Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726(VS.100).aspx) feature in MS Visual Studio or use Teststack.White framework that is based on UI Automation API.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately UIA has the same limitations as QTP. The application just doesn't expose a lot of elements that I need to control, so I am left using x,y coords based on the parent panel.